# Pylance violating the Commutative Law with Union type ordering

Tags: python, logic, python-typing, discrete-mathematics, pylance

I have an interface specifying a `position` member. Because I want it to be agnostic to whether the member is implemented as a `@property` or a direct attribute, I annotate the type as a Union of the two

```py
class Moveable(Protocol):
    position: property or Tuple[int, int]

entity: Moveable = Player() # Player implements `.position` as a getter
```

This works. However, switching the types around results in a Pylance error.

```py
class Moveable(Protocol):
    position: Tuple[int, int] or property
```

```
(class) Player()
Expression of type "Player" cannot be assigned to declared type "Moveable"
  "Player" is incompatible with protocol "Moveable"
    "position" is invariant because it is mutable
    "position" is an incompatible type
      "property" is incompatible with "Tuple[int, int]"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

I'm not seeing why the order would matter, as `(P or Q) <-> (Q or P)`. This violates [the Commutative Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property#Commutative_operations)

Comment: `or` is not the same as `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `or`, use `Union[]` or `|`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

Comment: Could have sworn it was the same result when I tried `Union`. Thanks